# How to check that a date has year greater than 2000 with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am having a Regex for Date as below.

```
^([0-2]\d|3[0-1]|[1-9])\-(0\d|1[0-2]|[1-9])\-([2]\d{3})$
```

It is allowing Date like 1-1-2000. But I need a modified Regex which can only allow dates with year greater than 2000.

I need to use modified Regex.

Comment: don't parse dates with regex.

Comment: You are better off using built-in datetime library. If you can't use a datetime library, try to split the string into pieces, and check the year part.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have to use Regex for this Requirement.

Comment: At least this still allows me to enter 30-2-2001. Not many places accept such dates :-)

Comment: Which environment/language are you working in? What have you tried to modify the regex?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am having no problem with case stated by you. I need to allow any Year greater than 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^([0-2]\d|3[0-1]|[1-9])\-(0\d|1[0-2]|[1-9])\-(2\d{2}[1-9]|2\d[1-9]0|[3-9]\d{3}|\d{2,}\d{3})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kA0qE6/3)

**Note:** `\d{2,}\d{3}` in `Group 3` can be written shotly like this: `\d{5,}`.

Comment: This is not allowing 1-1-2010 as Date.

Answer (score 0):

[^([0-2]\d|3[0-1]|[1-9])-(0\d|1[0-2]|[1-9])-([2-9]\d{2}[1-9]|[2-9][1-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d[1-9]\d)$](https://regex101.com/r/pP9jK3/1)

But don't parse date with regexp. Datetime has many formats and You can't parse all.

Comment: This regex will reject `1-1-3000`.

Comment: @Stephan tnx, realy not parse. How You generate image for this regex?